# Database high CPU utilisation during magento indexing

Tags: mysql, magento, amazon-rds

Magento is creating 700 + connections leading to database breakdown whenever cache is flushed or indexing is triggered. Production site remain down for 20 mins till all connections clears. 
All connections firing same query. And remain in state creating sort index. Using very high database configuration. 
DB on Amazon  rds.Any help is appreciated. This is breaking our production  site.

Comment: put in some code so that we could have a look. If it's nothing to do with the code, this question would be answered better in [Server fault](http://serverfault.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: "SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, main_table.`name`, main_table.`path`, `main_table`.`is_active`, `main_table`.`is_anchor`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND url_rewrite.product_id IS NULL AND url_rewrite.store_id='1' AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%' WHERE (main_table.is_active = '1') AND (main_table.include_in_menu = '1') AND (main_table.path like '1/2/%') ORDER BY `main_table`.`position` ASC"

Comment: above query is fired with status struck at Creating sort index 500 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why there is load balancer (Mysql - Master Slave architecture). Let me explain how it works.

1. There is a master database. 2)
2. There are multiple slaves (replica) databases connected to the master.

Whenever there is a write on the master database the slaves are also updated. This will make the slaves updated as like the master containing the updated data. Whenever you want to perform any optimization or the db gets down then you can switch the database to one of the slave avoiding the downtime. When the master is up and running again you can anytime switch to that database.

Check this link :

https://severalnines.com/blog/how-cluster-magento-nginx-and-mysql-multiple-servers-high-availability

Hope this helps you.